# How to switch "/" back to writable mode without reboot?

Tags: rhel, mount, readonly, root-filesystem

```
[root@SERVER .ssh]# mount|grep -i " / "
/dev/mapper/rootvg-root_lv on / type ext3 (rw)
[root@SERVER .ssh]# mount -o remount /
mount: block device /dev/rootvg/root_lv is write-protected, mounting read-only
[root@SERVER .ssh]#
```

How can I make the "/" writable again without a reboot?

```
[root@SERVER ~]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-ia32:graphics-3.1-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)
Release:    5.4
Codename:   Tikanga
[root@SERVER ~]#
```

UPDATE:

```
[root@SERVER ~]# lvdisplay rootvg/root_lv
  Locking type -1 initialisation failed.
[root@SERVER ~]# lvdisplay rootvg/root_lv --ignorelockingfailure
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/rootvg/root_lv
  VG Name                rootvg
  LV UUID                2Cccd4-oGrx-ssQW-xzK5-MZuA-g4NS-tFDFpd
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                2.00 GB
  Current LE             64
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

[root@SERVER ~]# lvchange -p rw rootvg/root_lv
  Locking type -1 initialisation failed.
[root@SERVER ~]# 
[root@SERVER ~]# lvchange --ignorelockingfailure -p rw rootvg/root_lv
  Only -a permitted with --ignorelockingfailure
  Run `lvchange --help' for more information.
[root@SERVER ~]#
```

should I use the "-a" function?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/37600/read-only-root-file-system-ext3-error and take a look at Womble's answer.

Comment: Sounds like the device itself, not the filesystem, is currently in write-protect mode. Look at the hardware settings?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this on my system. I'd try the -a option, but I suspect you experience some other problem prior to this point.

Answer (score 1):

Check `lvdisplay rootvg/root_lv`.  If it shows that the LV is in read-only mode, you will need to make it read-write.  Assuming the LV is in a healthy state, this can be done by `lvchange -p rw`.

Comment: I updated the question, it didn't worked :\

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think</strike> `mount -o remount,rw /` <strike>should do</strike> won't work, as stated in a comment below.

Comment: The block device here is read-only, so remount will fail.

Comment: @JodieC OK, I see. Edited my answer to reflect so.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, searching for that, I found an answer that said we should reboot in single user mode and run fsck on the disk in question.  That resolved our issue.

Comment: I was about to comment that "disk went read-only on me" is normally due to filesystem corruption or some hardware problem.